# What does it mean when something says that UNIX device files are static?

Tags: udev, history

I've been reading up on [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev). In the "overview" section, Wikipedia states that "unlike traditional Unix systems, where the device nodes in the /dev directory have been a static set of files, the Linux udev device manager dynamically provides only the nodes for the devices actually present on a system".

What does it mean when it says "static set of files"? Does it mean that there are always `/dev` files but they don't always point to a real device?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you're referring to this paragraph:

> Unlike traditional Unix systems, where the device nodes in the /dev directory have been a static set of files, the Linux udev device manager dynamically provides only the nodes for the devices actually present on a system. Although devfs used to provide similar functionality, Greg Kroah-Hartman cited a number of reasons[3](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/SVN-20131015/chapter07/udev.html) for preferring its implementation over devfs:

From the 1st sentence they're referring to other Unix systems where the devices in `/dev` are statically created and persisted from reboot to reboot. Previous versions of Linux (think the 2.4 version of the Kernel) used to work this way too, newer versions no longer behave in this manner. Other Unixes typically include a common set of device files when you install them, and only rarely is it necessary to manually create additional ones.

In 2.4 you could use the `mknod` command to manually to create any necessary device files. For example:

```
$ mknod ./dev/random b 12 5
```

**NOTE:** This is stating create the `/dev/random` file descriptor, as a block device with major device number of 12 and a minor device number of 5.

#### Device files under /dev

The OP asked the following follow-up question regarding the overall functionality of the `/dev` directory. Here's his question:

> Can you add details on the technical method used to persist device files across reboots? how are they physically stored on disk? did they need special filesystem support?

In researching this I figured I'd start with the [Linux From Scratch project](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) to get a basic idea of how `/dev` is managed in newer versions of the Linux kernel. I know that in the past (think Kernel versions 2.4 and before) the `/dev` directory was a static set of files that literally took up space on the HDD, but with the advent of `udev` and `sysfs` this was no longer the case.

Traditionally, these special files were created at install time by the distribution, using the `mknod` command. In recent years, Linux systems began using `udev` to manage these `/dev` files at runtime. For example, `udev` will create nodes when devices are detected and delete them when devices are removed (including hotplug devices at runtime). This way, the `/dev` directory contains (for the most part) only entries for devices which actually exist on the system at the current time, as opposed to devices which could exist.

So gone are the days of having to worry about your device files under `/dev`. This directory is now completely managed by `udev` and `sysfs` from reboot to reboot.

#### Additional `udev` & `sysfs` resources

- [libudev and Sysfs Tutorial](http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/)
- [7.4. Device and Module Handling on an LFS System](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/SVN-20131015/chapter07/udev.html)
- [Linux For You Magazine Articles - A series on Linux Device Drivers](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/05/decoding-character-device-file-operations/)

#### References

- [Create Special Files With ‘mknod’](http://www.lainoox.com/tag/linux-mknod-example/)
- [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6 - mknod](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/mknod.html)

Comment: It's not "older" Unix systems, it is traditional Unix systems.  OpenBSD still uses static entries.  It's even a relatively recent invention in Linux to have dynamic entries.

Comment: Also, for the sake of the record, it was (and continues to be) rater rare to need to create device files by hand.  Most operating systems would populate /dev with a large number of device files on install that would cover most uses.  One generally only had/have to create them with unusual hardware combinations.  I do this on my OpenBSD-based serial console server that has 3 8-port serial cards.

Comment: @kurtm - expanded A based on your feedback, thanks.

Comment: @slm can you add details on the technical method used to persist device files across reboots? how are they physically stored on disk? did they need special filesystem support?

Comment: @strugee - sure, the process varies from distro to distro. I've been looking at how LSF does it for specifics, how much of this do you want to see in the A? http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/SVN-20131015/chapter07/udev.html

Comment: @slm ah, nice link. probably just a small paragraph that says "it used to be a startup script, but now it's udev via `sysfs`."

Comment: @strugee - OK, I'll add it in a bit. At work now.

Comment: @strugee - let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

"device files" are a special type of file (in much the same way directories, symlinks, named pipes and unix domain sockets are special types of file). They do not store user data directly, instead they store a major and minor device number and a device type (char or block). Filesystems designed for unix-like systems will have support for storing device files.

When a "device file" is accessed either by an application or through a mount command the major and minor device number and the device type are retrived from the filesystem. Based on these numbers the kernel selects the driver and opens it.

Traditionally device files just existed in a directory on the root filesystem called /dev , usually created by a tool called "MAKEDEV" which reads configuration files and creates device nodes. This is reffered to as a static set up and was used for many years by pretty much every unix-like OS including linux. There are a few downsides to this approach.

- Device files existed even if the corresponding hardware was not present in the current system. It was difficult to tell what hardwas was or was not present.
- If a kernel upgrade introduced new device types then the admin would likely have to manually create device nodes for them.
- There was a limited supply of major and minor numbers, statically assigning a pair to every possible device node (remember one physical device can have many device nodes due to partitioning) was not scalable.

linux's first attempt at solving this problem was called devfs (some other unix-like operating systems also have a filesystem called devfs but I don't know the details). This was a virtual filesystem where the kernel would provide device nodes. Afaict it was relatively stillborn, it pushed it's own nonstandard device naming scheme whether you liked it or not and didn't offer massive advantages over a static /dev

Later udev came along. This used a different model. A tmpfs was mounted on /dev and a userspace dameon managed the device nodes in it based on notifications from the kernel. https://lwn.net/Articles/65197/

More recently there has also been something called devtmpfs. This seems to be something of a compromise where the kernel creates a set of basic device nodes, but userspace can take over if more complex functionality is desired.

Answer (score 0):

On the Altos 386 (i386/SCO SysV Unix) system an example of a static device that had to be created at kernel upgrade (or re install) was the plethora of /dev/mt entries to support SCSI HP Dat Tape units. The major number was for the tape driver on SCSI Bus and the minors were for the SCSI device number and features (raw, rewind no rewind come to mind). There were two SCSI busses and they could support multiple mixed tape units and mounted HD extension file systems on each bus.

The dev's were just entries in the root file system made with MAKEDDEV. For practical purposes they could be linked to more usable names so the rewind device on SCSI device 5 could be linked to /dev/st (SCSI tape to distinguish it from an inbuilt DC300 unit)

Later we had to do the same when we started using Slackware Linux and had to manually patching the .99b kernel to use 3Com 3C509b combo ethernet cards correctly. These had cat5, BNC and AUI connectors and the sport was getting the right interface up at boot time